# .Net program runs slow until renamed

Tags: .net, windows, performance

VB.net 4.0 32bit WinForms app on a Windows 2012 R2 Remote Desktop server.

I have a few .net programs that take a long time to get to the main screen on a particular server (>45 seconds). Other .net programs load fast (5 seconds) on the same server, they are basically doing the same start up routines as the slow programs but are for different parts of a suite of software.

I recompiled one of the programs and changed the version number, but it still loads slow.

If I copy a slow program to another folder on the same server its slow.

If I copy a slow program to another folder on **another server** its fast.

If I **simply copy and paste** any of the slow programs so they have "- Copy" (or anything different about the name) they run fast.

I can take any of the fast programs and rename them to one of the slow program name and the now run super slow.

I created a simple winforms app to display the version of .net installed on a label on a form. It runs super fast (1 second), unless i rename it to one of the slow program names (10 seconds).

I've copied other .net programs not compiled by my company that load fast on that server until i rename them to one of the slow program names, then they load super slow.

I copied Notepad (a non .net program) and the mui file and renamed them to match the name of a slow program. It did open fast.

The apps are not signed, I ngen uninstalled all .net apps/dlls used by the software so that none were in listed in the native app cache. 
Obviously rebooted all the servers, Kaspersky Antivirus and firewall are off. Windows firewall is off, no other antivirus programs running. No other non-Microsoft programs are installed on the server.
I later ngen installed the apps but still no difference.

The server's cpu/network/disk are not under stress at all, all basically flatlined. Average disk read/write speeds never got above 3ms.

I used procmon to compare the output of the file running slow, versus the same program renamed running fast. Side by side they flow basically the same way during start up. The slow one is looking in the registry around HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Nls\ExtendedLocale then has NO activity for 5+ seconds and then looks in the registry around HKLM\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\Windows Error reporting\WMR and carries on. The fast version does then same thing milliseconds from each other.

The server's Region is set to English (United States) with no changes from the normal. Time and Timezone are set correctly.

Comment: Check for network traffic with SysInternals' TCPView.  Could be CRL checks.  Next create a minidump just as the process freezes so you can see what it is doing.

Comment: Are the slow programs running under IIS or similar? If so, it can be related to the utilized ApplicationPool- may be overpopulated of applications there or bad settings - and renaming them cause to run into default POOL instead the problematic one.

Comment: No, they are winforms apps. Also I didn't see anything unusual with TCPView.